# Find and classify all isolated singularities of $f(z)=\frac{3z^2-1}{z(z^2+1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given

$$f(z)=\dfrac{3z^2-1}{z(z^2+1)}$$

I also have to find, classify, and compute the residue at each singularity. So, the first thing I've done is expand this to get a better view of whats going on

$$f(z)=\frac{3(z+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3})(z-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3})}{z(z-i)(z+i)}$$

From this, we obviously have singularities, I'm still a bit confused on the classifications of them. I think this is only when we have undefined function values, not necessarily a $\frac{0}{0}$ situation. Even still, we have problems at $z=\pm i, 0$. We get $0$ when $z=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$, but I don't think those count as singularities. Looking at the $z=\pm i, 0$ solutions, we cannot factor and reduce any of them, so they're not removable. I don't know how to distinguish between poles and essential.

From there, calculating the residues of each one is also a bit confusing. I think that's done by computing this limit

$$\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)(z-z_0)$$ for each $z_0$. In this case I believe would just be the three, $\pm i, 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{3z^{2}-1}{z(z^{2}+1)}$,

**Finding the singularities:**

- $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{3z^{2}-1}{z(z-i)(z+i)}$ so singularities at $z=0, z=i$ and $z=-i$.

**Classifying each singularities:**

Using the following fact:

> $z_{0}$ is an isolated singularity and $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to 0}(z-z_{0})^{n}f(z)=A\not=0$ so $z_{0}$ is a pole of order $n$ and when $n=1$, $z_0$ is a simple pole.

- $\boxed{z_0=0}:$   $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to 0}(z-0)^{1}\left(\frac{3z^{2}-1}{z(z-i)(z+i)}\right)=-1\not=0$ so $z_{0}=0$ is a simple pole.
- $\boxed{z_1=i}:$ $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to i}(z-i)^{1}\left(\frac{3z^{2}-1}{z(z-i)(z+i)}\right)=2\not=0$ so $z_{1}=i$ is a simple pole.
- $\boxed{z_2=-i}:$ $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to -i}(z+i)^{1}\left(\frac{3z^{2}-1}{z(z-i)(z+i)}\right)=2\not=0$ so $z_{2}=-i$ is a simple pole.

Note that since $0,\pm i$ they are simple poles so cannot be essential singularities. *Is there singularities at infinity?*

**Residue at each singularity:**

Using the following fact:

> If $z_{0}$ is a simple pole, then $\displaystyle {\rm Res}(f,z_{0})=\lim_{z\to z_{0}}(z-z_{0})f(z)$.

- $\boxed{z_{0}=0}:$ $\displaystyle {\rm Res}(f,0)=\lim_{z\to 0}(z-0)f(z)=-1$.
- $\boxed{z_{1}=i}:$ $\displaystyle {\rm Res}(f,i)=\lim_{z\to i}(z-i)f(z)=2$.
- $\boxed{z_{2}=-i}:$ $\displaystyle {\rm Res}(f,-i)=\lim_{z\to -i}(z+i)f(z)=2$.

Comment: This makes things much clearer. That completely makes sense. So, before we even compute the limits, we already know their orders are each one, because the power of each factor is one? IF the limit evaluated to $0$, what would that indiciate?

Comment: You can expand in Laurent series at $0$ we have $f(z)=-\frac{1}{z}+\mathcal{O}(z)$ and $i$ we have $f(z)=\frac{2}{z-i}+\mathcal{O}(z-i)$ and $z=-i$ we have $f(z)=\frac{2}{z+i}+\mathcal{O}(z+i)$ so all simples poles and $z^{*}=\infty$ we have $f(z)=\frac{3}{z}-\frac{3}{z^{2}}+\frac{4}{z^{5}}+\mathcal{O}(\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{6})$.